# Street blocks as polygons in OpenStreetMap

Tags: qgis, polygon, openstreetmap

I want to convert OSM street blocks for a given area into polygons in QGIS (see image).  I can of course manually draw lines with OSM as a base layer, and then convert these lines into polygons.  However, this is a very tedious job.   Is there a better way of getting this done ?

[image]

Comment: Can you use something like the Overpass API online to query OSM for the raw data? Or get a raw OSM file from somewhere like GeoFabrik and extract the buildings layer? I assume your image above is from OSM raster tiles?

Comment: The image is a manaul drawing.  I can get the exepcted result on screen by buffering the street lines and afterwards creating a symmetric difference with the area.   But the result returns a single multipolygon image that cannot be split up into the individual polygons.  At least, not as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, I thought the grey was building outlines. You only have road centerlines? So you need to buffer out the road width? Hmmm. But you can do Multipolygon-to-Polygon in QGIS, I'm sure...

Comment: You might get the result by using OSM land use types. e.g. in my neighbourhood, landuse=residential and landuse=commercial would work pretty well (they don't overlap roads, so they model the idea of a "street block" quite well). https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:landuse

Comment: @alphabetasoup : I tried your solution, but since I am working mostly with developing countries, landuse is hardly or not at all available in OSM for these areas

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out.  Here is the sequence of actions in order to obtain the proper result :

1. first, buffer your lines
2. next, create a symetric difference
3. finally, use 'multiple to individual'

This will get you the individual street blocks, each as a single polygon